# Initiates the Excel export (Large number of rows) using kendoGrid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

After the data get loaded in the Grid , I have a requirement to '**Export to Excel**' This works perfectly when i have lesser number of rows around 100s but now I am getting data which is exactly 12250 rows. This is getting loaded to the Grid but when I try to  '**Export to Excel**' its not working.

**This load's my grid**`

```
.Columns(column =>
            {
                column.Bound(p => p.CBCustomerName).Title("CB Customers");
                column.Bound(p => p.CBReceiveDateTimeUTC).Title("CB Date").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
                column.Bound(p => p.CBExpirationDate).Title("CBExpiration Date").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}");               

            })
            //.Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBound"))
            .Sortable()
            .Scrollable()
            .Filterable()
            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Group(x=> { x.Add(p => p.ReceiveDateTimeUTC);})
            .PageSize(20)
            .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("uspPendingWork", "PendingWork").Data("getGridData"))

        )`
```

'**Export to Excel**'

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ExportXL").on('click', function () {
                var grid = $("#PendingWorkGrid").data("kendoGrid");
                grid.saveAsExcel();
                $("#SearchBT").click();
            })
        });
```

**NOTE:** Loading to Grid is working properly.
**NOTE:** Export to Excel also works when rows are less(around 100 or 200)
      **But If rows are more like 12250 "Export to Excel" is not happening.**

Please let me if I can correct something. So that I will be able to export to excel.

Comment: Does the browser console show any errors or messages ? How many groups are there ? How long do you wait before deciding it was not happening ? Was the number of rows threshold for not happening consistent (what happens between row count 200 and 12250) ?

Comment: Infect I have verified its export till 5000/6000 rows. But after that nothing is happening. In my case rows are around 70,000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit of records (row items) that can be exported to Excel from client-side function varies between browsers, [as Daniel said in a similar issue](https://www.telerik.com/forums/export-to-excel-silently-fails-in-chrome):

> Every browser has its own limitations and I'm afraid that in most cases we
>   don't have control over them. That said, **exporting large amounts of
>   data during export will generate strings that might be too long for
>   the given browser.**

Because file contents constructed entirely in client-side, it depends in each browser ability to store formatted strings (e.g. JSON) that processed by [`Spreadsheet.saveAsExcel()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/spreadsheet/methods/saveasexcel) function.

If you want exporting to Excel file with large amount of records/rows (say 12,250 rows), I recommend using server-side processing by utilizing `Telerik.Documents.SpreadsheetStreaming` namespace to generate in-memory stream of exported records, then convert it to a byte array which can be passed as `FileResult`. Here is an example to perform server-side processing in controller action method (some parts snipped for brevity):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(int rowsCount, string fileName)
{
    // column header names, separated by comma
    string[] columnHeaderNames = { "CBCustomerName", "CBReceiveDateTimeUTC", "CBExpirationDate" };

    // column width values, separated by comma    
    double[] columnWidths = { 30, 14.5, 14.5 };

    SpreadDocumentFormat exportFormat = SpreadDocumentFormat.Xlsx;
    string mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    string ext = "xlsx";

    string fileNameWithExt = string.Format("{0}.{1}", fileName, ext);

    // byte array to hold MemoryStream result
    byte[] rendered = null;

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (IWorkbookExporter workbook = SpreadExporter.CreateWorkbookExporter(exportFormat, stream))
        {
            using (IWorksheetExporter worksheet = workbook.CreateWorksheetExporter("WorksheetName"))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < columnWidths.Length; i++)
                {
                    using (IColumnExporter columnExport = worksheet.CreateColumnExporter())
                    {
                        // export column settings here
                    }
                }

                // other stuff

                for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowsCount; rowIndex++)
                {
                    using (IRowExporter rowExport = worksheet.CreateRowExporter())
                    {
                        // export row settings here
                    }
                }

                // other stuff
            }
        }

        rendered = stream.ToArray();
    }

    return File(rendered, mimeType, fileNameWithExt);
}
```

Similar issues:

[Export to Excel Row Limit](https://www.telerik.com/forums/export-to-excel-row-limit)

[Excel export not working with more than a thousand records](https://www.telerik.com/forums/excel-export-not-working-with-more-than-a-thousand-records)

Additional references (server-side export to Excel):

[Large Document Export with SpreadsheetStreaming (Telerik Example)](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/spreadstreamprocessing)

[GridExcelSpreadProcessing example](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net-mvc/tree/master/grid-dpl-integration/GridExcelSpreadProcessing)

Answer (score 0):

Found out a simple solution for this. After some research came to know that if data size is more then the only option is **Server Side Export Implementation**

```
<button id="ExportXL" name="ExportXL" type="button" value="Export to Excel" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "Controler Name")'" />



public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
    {
        using (var excel = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            var workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet Name");
            workSheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(result, PrintHeaders: true, TableStyle: OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium6);
            workSheet.Cells[workSheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
            return File(excel.GetAsByteArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Reports.xlsx");
        }

    }
```

** result is your collection of data (Which you might have from your DB)

** TableStyle: OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium6  - Excel row Style

** **ExcelPackage** - ([EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/)) Can include on Package config ----> Install-Package EPPlus -Version 4.5.1