# Kendo Grid Export Not working more than 50000 records

Tags: kendo-ui

I have Kendo-Grid which is holding the records more than 50000.Now I'm going to do export then. I'm getting browser unresponsive.How can I solve this problem. Can we have any work around for this.

We have already built in JSON reedy with holding more than 50000 records, 
We don not have any server side code. we have done at client side only.

Comment: Which Kendo? Exporting to which format?

Comment: Assuming excel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49922780/initiates-the-excel-export-large-number-of-rows-using-kendogrid